# Filter, Sort and Paginate in mongoose returns duplicate value

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a *product* document in mongodb. I am retrieving data with paging using *skip* and *limit* after filtering and sorting, like this using *mongoose* -

```
Product.find({gender:'male'})
  .sort(price: 1)
  .skip(page * 25).limit(25);
```

When page value is 0 it returns the result as expected, but when the page value changes to 1 it returns **some** results that were already retrieved when page value was 0. I am passing all these parameters through query in *nodjs express*. How can i retrieve unique value only with sorting and filtering while using pagination with mongoose ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/#sort-consistency):

> MongoDB does not store documents in a collection in a particular order. When sorting on a field which contains duplicate values, documents containing those values may be returned in any order.
>
> If consistent sort order is desired, include at least one field in
> your sort that contains unique values. The easiest way to guarantee
> this is to include the `_id` field in your sort query.

So you can solve the problem by:

```
Product.find({gender:'male'})
  .sort({price: 1, _id: 1})
  .skip(page * 25).limit(25);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for quick response. Yeah it is working.